# Ext-js: How to resize / close browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

Does Ext-js come with functionality to manipulate the browser window?

Specifically, I want to resize and close the current browser window.

(Browser window, the browser's native window, as opposed to Ext-js' widgets).

It it possible or must I resort to plain old javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Ext JS does not have any functionality to support changing the browser window.  Ext JS what originally designed run on top of other frameworks like jQuery and Prototype, so when run by its self it does not contain many non-widget methods.

You would have to default to using [`window.resizeTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.resizeTo) or [`window.close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close).

If you need to let Ext JS know that you have changed the size of the window you can register an event using `Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize`.  Take a look the method documentation on the ExtJS site: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.EventManager